# Could a nice principe, or at least a simpler alternative proof, be found regarding a lemma of Gauss

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

To prove the quadratic reciprocity law, Gauss needed the following lemma:

> If $p$ is a prime number congruent to 1 modulo 8, then there exists a prime $q<p$ such that $p$ is a non residue modulo $q$.

Gauss demonstrated this result in no 126, 127, 128, 129 of the *Disquisitiones*, and it is in fact the essential difficulty of the quadratic reciprocity law (with this lemma, I could provide a terrible simplification of the original proof of Gauss by induction).

I found the demonstration of Gauss both beautiful and amazing, in some sense natural too.
But I feel there is something more, hidden there, a general principle or a beautiful elementary lemma of modular theory (akin to Thue's lemma for example), which would provide a much more luminous and simpler demonstration to this result.

Can someone try to extract it? Or maybe someone already knows how to do that?

N.B: I'm not sure there is an available translation to English, but here is an available translation of the [Disquisitiones](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k29060d) in French (I know there is also one in German).

Comment: There is an English translation of the Disquisitiones.

Comment: Could you provide the link?

Comment: I don't have a link; I have the book.

Comment: Well, I guess few persons would afford that book. It's a pity an English translation is not available online for free (apparently).

Comment: It was US $\$2.95$ in 1965. Math libraries ought to have it.

Comment: So, have you tried a library?

Comment: Personally, I have no problem to read and understand French, so I use the online resource linked above.

Comment: also asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/404268/11260